# what is the best method to rename project name in every where from Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

what is a straight forward method or any to rename a project name (project name, virtual project folder name, physical project folder name.. etc) from Xcode 5 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- First close xCode
- Copy your Project folder (in my case called FirstName) to Desktop
- Rename the Project folder (in my case SecondName)
- Now open the new Project folder and start xCode by clicking the .xcodeproj file
- Change the Name of the app in the left top corner by double clicking it slowly:

[image: rename app]

- Rename everything they recommend

[image]

- Save and close xCode
- Put the renamed Project folder back in your xCode Projects folder and you are done!

Comment: When I did this with Xcode 11.3 on Catalina, it changed the name everywhere except in the Main Menu. That still has the old name. The menu item to close the app has been changed properly, but not the app name itself in the Main Menu. I've been poring over the code trying to find out where that didn't get change with no luck so far.

Comment: My answer was working almost 10 years ago on Xcode 6. I don't think you should try this on the current version of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks. I'm finding that a lot of the online Xcode advice is either for ancient versions or versions newer than what I have. Xcode 11 still has the feature that attempt to change the name everywhere for you, so it wasn't like I'm attempting something obsolete or deprecated (except to the extent that Apple doesn't test *everything* as they upgrade).

I had previously been trying to find diffs in the two projects using the terminal command "diff -rq" and when I resorted to pasting that output into a spreadsheet to dissect it line by line, I was inspired to try Meld, DirEqual, and FreeFileSync.