# Copying xCode projects

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode5

How can I create  a copy of xCode project?
I mean I want copy directory with full project functionality, setting, files, images and so on. Basically I want to change only project name. I use xCode 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered the same question the other day, look at this [what is the best method to rename project name in every where from Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031576/what-is-the-best-method-to-rename-project-name-in-every-where-from-xcode-5/24032022#24032022)